# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre agrio, ácido y amargo?

Tags: traducción, sinónimos, comida

Estuve investigando sobre los [5 sabores básicos que puede sentir el humano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste).
En particular los que me interesa traducir y llegar a consenso son, en inglés, *bitter* y *sour*. *Sour* está asociado al limón, por lo tanto sí o sí va con ácido. Por eliminación, *bitter* es amargo.

En el [artículo de wiki en español de sabor ácido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabor_%C3%A1cido), se menciona agrio como sinónimo, pero no amargo.

En el de [sabor amargo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabor_amargo) no se menciona ni ácido ni agrio.

Todo esto parece indicar que el problema está resuelto:

- Sour: ácido, agrio.
- Bitter: amargo.

Pero prueben estas [traducciones de Google 'amargo'](https://translate.google.com.ar/#es/en/amargo). ¡No debería aparecer ácido! Contradicción.

Ahora vean [esta entrada de 'amargo'](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/amargo), citando *amargar* como sinónimo (incorrectamente) de acidular y agriar.

Mi pregunta es, en español, ¿somos coherentes en este sentido, o no somos tan rigurosos?

Nótese que comentaron @Rodrigo y @Rafael que acido y amargo NO son lo mismo como sabores, pero como adjetivos de personas, peyorativos, sí pueden usarse similarmente. Lo cual no explica la entrada del diccionario de mas arriba.

La traduccion de Google contradictoria con mis ideas la dejo como evidencia de que hay tendencia a confundir/no ser rigurosos en la diferencia, aunque reconozco, no es nada autoritario.

Comment: El traductor de Google no es una buena fuente. Probablemente traduce _bitter_ como "ácido" en su sentido "espiritual" (mordaz, sarcástico, corrosivo, áspero...), no físico.

Comment: Y si buscas en WordReference un sinónimo de _bitter_ también te tira _acid_ y _sour_. No hay que pedirle al idioma a priori clasificaciones con rigurosidad científica, tampoco al inglés.

Comment: y recuerda que wiki es hecho por gente común. Wiki no es la ley

Comment: Tal como dice @Rodrigo, ácido y amargo son ideas afines cuando no se usan para sabores, sino como analogía a actitudes de personas. Creo que de ahí la confusión. [Agrio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1A9DuNy), por su parte, es prácticamente sinónimo de [ácido](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/agrio).

Comment: Además de la falta de rigor que mencionan los comentarios anteriores, en cuestiones de carácter, el inglés *sour* se traduciría al español más bien como *amargo* o *amargado*. *John is sour since his girlfriend left him* --> *John está amargado desde que su novia le dejó*.

Comment: @Rodrigo me da que tus comentarios dan para una muy buena respuesta : )

Comment: I think you need to either (a) invent a way of sending flavours over the internet, or (b) invite a mixed group of Hispanophone and Anglophone readers of this SE to your place and give us a range of foodstuffs to taste so we can finally knock this one on the head.

Comment: Para mi algo agrio es algo que se ha acidificado y normalmente echado a perder, como la leche que cuando se estropea y se acidifica se dice que ha agriado.
A partir de aquí el español se habla en muchos sitios y hay diferencias notables de unos a otros con lo que todo lo que me diga la RAE, me lo creo que para eso están.

Answer (score 4):

Quizá las diferencias son tan imperceptibles de manera consciente, que solo pueden matizarse a muy bajo nivel.

He añadido aquí una respuesta que he encontrado en [Yahoo Answers](https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081120163708AARD3ox)

> El sabor **amargo** es uno de los cinco sabores básicos es el más
>   necesitado de hábitos para que sea gusto adquirido y es debido a que
>   es quizás el más desagradable de los cinco. **Se detecta mediante las
>   papilas gustativas ubicadas en la parte posterior de la lengua**. Los
>   investigadores de la biología evolutiva han sugerido que **este sabor es
>   interpretado como desagradable en muchas culturas debido al mecanismo
>   de defensa que muestra la necesidad de sobrevivir evitando los
>   envenenamientos, esto es así debido a que la mayoría de los venenos
>   son amargos en su sabor**.[1] [2] Se ha descubierto a comienzos del
>   siglo XXI que **los receptores de la sensación de amargo son unos
>   sensores denominados T2R**.
>
> El **sabor ácido** (a menudo se identifica también con el sabor agrio) es
>   uno de los cinco sabores básicos **detectado por las papilas gustativas
>   de la lengua ubicadas a ambos lados de la parte posterior de la misma**.
>   Los sensores de las papilas gustativas detectan mediante canales
>   iónicos los iones oxonio (H3O+) que se forman al haber ácidos en
>   presencia de agua. Al igual que el sabor amargo, el ácido es
>   **considerado como una 'alarma' por el cerebro ya que algunas sustancias
>   venenosas y perjudiciales poseen sabores ácidos**.[1] Los **sensores
>   específicos en la lengua que detectan el sabor ácido se denominan
>   TAS2R**.[2] [3]

La diferencia radicará pues en su composición química y en los mecanismos del cerebro para diferenciar ambos sabores según estas composiciones.

Posiblemente por esto, por ser unos matices difíciles de apreciar que usamos los dos manera de manera indistinta.

Resumiendo:

- Ambos son sabores básicos.
- Ambos son detectados por las mismas papilas gustativas.
- Ambos son una alerta de posibles sustancias venenosas. Y sabiendo esto, tampoco sería necesario matizar por qué razón lo son. El cerebro busca la solución más rápida al problema de la supervivencia. Los detalles están de más.

Pero:

- Ambos tiene propiedades químicas diferentes y por ello tenemos receptores distintos para detectarlas.

En cuanto a **Agrio**:

Por más que leo, agrio **no se contempla como sabor básico**, sino como un matiz del sabor que indica acidez. Si buscas en Wikipedia por [Agrio](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sabor_agrio&redirect=no), ¡¡te redirige a ácido!! :-)

Cuanto más leo al respecto más me convence la idea de que es un matiz del sabor y no un sabor en sí mismo. Se emplea para describir el sabores de cítricos los cuales también describiríamos como ácidos.

La línea que separa estos tres conceptos es muy, muy fina.

Answer (score 2):

En realidad, "sour" es agrio y "acid" es ácido.
Entonces tendrías:

**ácido** - acidic

**amargo** - bitter

**agrio** - sour

De todas formas, se usa ácido como sinónimo de agrio tanto en español como en inglés, que para estas cosas es un poco más laxo que el español.

Comment: "En realidad" no es un argumento. Necesito por favor referencias. Te pido que veas el articulo de limon de wiki [en espaniol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrus_%C3%97_limon) y en [ingles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon). En ingles lo describen como "sour taste" en la cabecera, en espaniol como "sabor acido". Eso contradice lo que estas diciendo. Gracias!

Comment: Quizás este artículo te ayuda: https://colonnaandsmalls.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/the-difference-sourness-acidity/
Lo de Wikipedia responde a lo que señalan en ese texto, que se considera a "acid" y "sour" como sinónimos.

Answer (score 2):

Como mi idioma nativo es el español y no el inglés, debería centrarme en la diferencia entre agrio y ácido, que por otra parte es lo que creo que está creando la confusión en este caso, sin embargo me gustaría decir primero que cuando yo estudié inglés hace mucho, mucho tiempo, me enseñaron que bitter se traducía como amargo y sour como ácido.

Dicho lo cual, sigo creyendo que la causa de la duda en particular es precisamente la palabra *agrio*. Creo que es bastante fácil diferenciar entre los sabores amargos y los ácidos: amarga es la mostaza, el limón es ácido. No creo que haya controversia alguna a este respecto.
Entonces veamos lo que dice la RAE(por favor, no uses el traductor de google ¬¬, y coge con pinzas todo lo que leas en wikipedia) de la palabra agrio:

> [**agrio, gria**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1A9DuNy)
>   Del ant. agro2, con infl. de agriar.
>   1. adj. Que actuando sobre el gusto o el olfato produce sensación de acidez. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Que se ha agriado.
>   3. adj. Difícilmente accesible; pendiente o abrupto.
>   4. adj. Acre, áspero, desabrido. Genio agrio. Respuesta agria.
>   5. adj. Dicho de un castigo o de un sufrimiento: Difícilmente tolerable.
>   6. adj. Dicho de un metal: Frágil, quebradizo, no dúctil ni maleable.
>   7. adj. Pint. Dicho del colorido: Falto de armonía o consonancia, o de la necesaria entonación. U. t. c. s. m.
>   8. m. p. us. Zumo ácido.
>   9. m. pl. Frutas agrias o agridulces, como el limón, la naranja y otras semejantes.

Aparte de resaltar las definiciones número uno y ocho, me gustaría complementar la etimología de dicha palabra con un texto que aparece en una [página](http://etimologias.dechile.net/) que, por experiencia propia, es muy adecuada para este tipo de consultas y siempre acertada: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?agrio

De estas dos referencias(en la cita del DRAE también se incluye una pequeña etimología que concuerda con la de la otra página) se concluye sin mucho esfuerzo que las dos palabras tienen la misma raíz etimológica, y que en particular la palabra *agrio* se usa como sinónimo de *ácido*, que es la palabra más usada comúnmente(al menos en mi zona, y creo que en toda la península) para definir el sabor del que hablamos.

**Vamos, que es tan simple como una cuestión de sinónimos, aunque esta vez con la misma raíz etimológica, que no se ve tanto.**

---

En cuanto a la diferencia entre una persona "amarga" y una "ácida": primero, para definir a una persona yo nunca he visto usar la palabra "amarga" directamente(exceptuando licencias poéticas que ya sabemos que en el español son millones), sino *amargada*, refiriéndose más bien a algo así como un estado de tristeza sempiterno; segundo, el que una persona sea "ácida" se suele referir a que hace comentarios algo hirientes pero sin salirse de tono, llegando al quid de la cuestión rápidamente y sin exagerar.

No son palabras que se usen para lo mismo cuando se refieren a personas, aunque a este respecto no sabría decir para qué se usaría *agrio*... ¿para una persona *amargada* o para una persona *ácida*? Si lees la acepción número 4 que da la RAE de agrio:

> Acre, áspero, desabrido. Genio agrio. Respuesta agria.

Tampoco es que lo aclare mucho, y es que *agrio*, si bien se usa, personalmente siempre me ha dado la impresión de ser menos exacto, más general, no un sabor sino una mezcla de sabores o un matiz como ya dijeron otros. Aún estando claro que es sinónimo de ácido, y por tanto se refiere al mismo sabor, a mí siempre me ha dado esa otra impresión, que es solo eso, una impresión personal, pero creo que bastante acertada si se observa el contexto en que se suele usar la palabra.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, Nox. Muchas gracias por aportar tus conocimientos y búsqueda para tener una respuesta bastante próxima a lo canónica.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una diferencia entre lo que significa "agria" en español y lo que significa "sour" en inglés.

"Agria" es más limitada, más definitiva. "Sour" puede indicar "agria," pero "sour" también puede indicar "ácido".

La leche puede estar "sour" y los limones también pueden ser "sour", pero la leche nunca se llama en inglés "acidic".

"Acidic" es menos usada que "sour" relacionada con comidas.

Por ejemplo:  de un confite muy acido, un niño diría "It is very sour", no usaría "acidic".

También, usarlo de este sentido tendría que usar siempre "acidic" y no "acid" porque "acid" refiere a la liquida corosiva (o acid vs alkaline), sino la droga LSD. Más bien cuando usan "acidic" se relaciona con comida en sentido del PH.

Por ejemplo en una programa de cocina puede decirse que se necesita un ácido, la comida-- que necesita algo "acidic" para equilibrar sabores.  Eso es decir que la acida corte grasa, pero eso mas bien es ciencia de la cocina.

Pero por otro lado, en la mesa siempre dirían que la comida es "sour" si fuera demasiado ácida.

Comment: mis referencias: none, but English is my first language.

Comment: Hello Teresa and thanks for your answer. I spent some time fixing the format a bit and correcting some errors. However, it is still a bit confusing: could you [edit] it yourself and give some order to the ideas so we can polish this hidden gem?